# Powershell append CSV Error

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a csv file with only one column like below

```
Column1
Apple
Mango
```

I am try to append the csv to add more fruits by appending the current csv file with the following script

```
$path     = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$csvPathforFruits = $path + "\Fruits.csv"
$importFruit = Import-Csv $csvPathforFruits
$new = "Orange"
$new |  Export-CSV $csvPathforFruits -Append
```

But following error is thrown out.

```
Export-CSV : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\Test\Fruits.csv. The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: 
Colume1. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and then retry the command.
At C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\Test\tt.ps1:5 char:9
+ $new |  Export-CSV $csvPathforFruits -Append
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Colume1:String) [Export-Csv], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotAppendCsvWithMismatchedPropertyNames,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

Can anyone point out my mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single column CSV is basically a text file with an entry on each line. This will do what you're after.

There is no need to import the CSV. I have set the encoding to `utf8`; if you run into problems try `unicode`

```
$path     = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$csvPathforFruits = $path + "\Fruits.csv"

# In English: add a new line and then the word "Orange" to the bottom of the file.
"`nOrange" | Out-File $csvPathforFruits -Append -Encoding utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

When you import your CSV it is converted in to an object, you need to append a similar object but you are trying to append a string. Something like this would fix it:

```
$path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$csvPathforFruits = $path + "\Fruits.csv"
$importFruit = Import-Csv $csvPathforFruits

$new = New-Object psobject -Property @{Column1 = "Orange"}
$new | Export-CSV $csvPathforFruits -Append
```

Or even:

```
$path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$csvPathforFruits = $path + "\Fruits.csv"
$importFruit = Import-Csv $csvPathforFruits

$importFruit += New-Object psobject -Property @{Column1 = "Orange"}
$importFruit | Export-CSV $csvPathforFruits -NoTypeInformation
```

But if your file is just one column of text then treating as a CSV seem to be overkill.